# Using identical list comprehensions on two separate lists

Tags: python

This feels like a simple question, but I haven't been able to figure it out and I haven't been able to find the answer anywhere.

In one line, how can I use two identical list comprehensions on two different lists, and return the results as two seperate lists?

I am trying to do this:

```
listx = [x for x in listx if x != None]
listy = [y for y in listy if y != None]
```

Is there a way to do this in one line? Perhaps using `map()` or a list comprehension?

Comment: Can you give an example of what your output should be?  Why does it need to be in one line?  Just as a challenge?

Comment: To avoid code repetition?

Comment: Then why not just write a function?

Comment: Yeah, you could write a function, but you might think it's overkill in this case. (Of course, you might think the answers given are overkill in this case too. One could easily argue that the two lines of code in the question are the most readable of the lot).

Comment: There is already a function for this, `listx = filter(None, listx)`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Though I don't get why it has to be a one-liner, this should do what you want:

```
listx, listy = [[x for x in alist if x != None] for alist in [listx, listy]]
```

Comment: Nice. Nested `list comprehension`.

Answer (score 3):

I think the original one and nested list comprehension is just fine and very readable.

However, if you want to think in terms of functions having an input and output:

You want to `filter` some contents from a list, so it can be written as:

```
listx = filter(None, listx)
listy = filter(None, listy)
```

There is a [repeated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) pattern. The pattern here is we are changing multiple lists at once.

```
map(function, collection)
```

So you can break down your original problem to `map` multiple `lists` using a `filter`.

```
listx, listy = map(lambda x: filter(None, x), [listx, listy])
```

Comment: "a set of `lists`" — perhaps "multiple `lists`"? (Just to ensure no-one thinks you mean a `set`...)

Answer (score 1):

As simple as:

```
listx, listy = [x for x in listx if x != None], [y for y in listy if y != None]
```

Comment: Is there is a problem with this solution? I don't really understand the need of using map or nested list comprehensions here

Comment: No problems. But we are repeating the code which probably can be avoided and that is what OP meant by one-liner :-)

Comment: If I were doing it this way, I'd split it into two lines (as in the question) for the sake of readability.

Comment: @landogardner I agree, but the question asked  a one-liner. To avoid code repeating a function is probably the best solution here. In terms of readability I don't see a reason to use map or nest list comprehensions.

Comment: @AndreyF Yeah, there definitely seems to be a trade-off in these examples between avoiding repetition and better readability.

Comment: Anyway, the reason I asked if something is wrong because some one down voted my answer.